# rsync how to do a checksum on rsync

Tags: linux, bash, rsync, checksum

When using rsync sometimes the rsync doesn't copy all the files done, below is my code I use. Is they a way to do a checksum or check after the rsync to see if all the files have been copied and if not try again until all files have been copied?

```
TEMP="/home/user/temp"
OPTS="-rav -h"

rsync $OPTS --stats user@example.com:/home/user/Local $TEMP
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to produce the situation when "`rsync` doesn't copy all the files"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is best solved by configuring `rsync` properly. Read the `man` page :) there's options (like `--checksum` for this).

You can do this on your own as well:

1. `find` all files in the rsync'd directory.
2. `xargs md5sum` to get a checksum for all files
3. `md5sum` the checksums

If you do that on both sides (local/remote), you'll have a a checksum to compare against.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - I'm reading the man page for rsync now - to be fair we have a lot of options here - is it checksum I should be looking at?

Comment: Why is `rsync` not copying those files in the first place? It should. I'm not withholding information here, I don't remember the flags either

Comment: Rsync is copying the files just not always on the first attempt (might be down to network issues,etc) but I would like to re-run the command with checksum to verify things

Comment: (You can do the checksum as I described above, `find | md5sum`). Or [see here](http://blog.iangreenleaf.com/2009/03/rsync-and-retrying-until-we-get-it.html)

Answer (score 29):

As hinted at by uʍop ǝpısdn's answer, `rsync -c` or `rsync --checksum` may do what you need.

> -c, --checksum: skip based on checksum, not mod-time & size
>
> This forces the sender to checksum every regular file using a
> 128-bit MD4 checksum.  It does this during the initial file-system
> scan as  it  builds the  list  of  all  available  files. The receiver
> then checksums its version of each file (if it exists and it has the
> same size as its sender-side counterpart) in order to decide which
> files need to be updated: files with either a changed size or a
> changed checksum are  selected  for  transfer. Since  this  whole-file
> checksumming  of  all files on both sides of the connection occurs in
> addition to the automatic checksum verifications that occur during a
> file's transfer, this option can be quite slow.
>
> Note that rsync always
> verifies that each transferred file was correctly reconstructed on the
> receiving side by checking  its  whole-file  checksum, but  that
> automatic  after-the-transfer  verification has nothing to do with
> this option's before-the-transfer "Does this file need to be updated?"
> check.

The concerns about this being slow are probably not relevant these days, and this seems to be a good option when you can't or don't want to rely on modification times.

Comment: Useful when working in Git and switching between branches with changed files, which keeps changing the update times on files that you don't intend to send from a particular branch.

Answer (score 3):

Use `rsync -Pahn --checksum /path/to/source /path/to/destination | sed '/\/$/d' | tee migration.txt`

`sed` removes directories from the checksum verification.
`tee` outputs to the screen and to the file at the same time.

Keep in mind that this might not be a suitable method if you have very large files, as the verification will take a long time.

[Source](https://techblog.jeppson.org/2014/10/verify-backup-integrity-with-rsync-sed-cat-and-tee/)